# Add class="row" to each 5 items in angular js

Tags: angular

I am new in `Angular` I want to add `class="row"` in each of 5 items how could I use index of array in parent div in this way I can use `[ngClass]="{row:index%5===0}`

```
<div class="grid-on">
    <div [ngClass]="{row:index%5===0}`>
        <div class="col-1-of-5" *ngFor="let category of categories;let index=index">
            <div class="item-box">
                <img src={{category.imagePath}} alt="" class="item box__img">
                <h3 class="heading-quaternary">{{category.name}}</h3>
                <p>{{category.description}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ng-class="($index +1)%5 ? '' : 'row'" (0 is already falsey in javascript so no need for the === 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you loop over all categories the you get a div for each anyway and some would have row class and some would not. I think what you want is to get a div with row class for each five categories. Then the best way to me is to calculate the number of rows you need in the typescript and set an array with the number of rows as elements of the array. Then you can use that array instead for looping over the div with row class.
Then for getting five elements for each row you can write a method which return only five elements based on the index of div with row class. Something like if index is 0 then return categories[0] to categories[4] and if 1 the categories[5] to categories[9] and so on. Look at the codes below:

in TypeScript:

```
rowNumber: number[];
      constructor() {
        this.rowNumber = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.categories.length / 5; i++) {
          this.rowNumber.push(i);
        }
      }

      getCurrentCategories(currentIndex) {
        let item = [];
        let firstIndex = currentIndex * 5;
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          let nextIndex = firstIndex + i;
          if (this.categories[nextIndex]){
            item.push(this.categories[nextIndex]);
          }
        }
        return item;
      }
```

In html:

```
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of rowNumber; let i=index">
        <div class="col-1-of-5 u-margin-t-small" *ngFor="let category of getCurrentCategories(i)">
            <div class="item-box">
                <img src={{category.imagePath}} alt="" class="item-box__img">
                <h3 class="heading-quaternary">{{category.name}}</h3>
                <p>{{category.description}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Note that the rowNumber can be set in any method that get the categories array. But for simplicity I just set it in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="grid-on">
    <div class="col-1-of-5" *ngFor="let category of categories;let index=index" [ngClass]="{row:index%5===0}`>
         <div class="item-box">
           <img src={{category.imagePath}} alt="" class="item box__img">
           <h3 class="heading-quaternary">{{category.name}}</h3>
           <p>{{category.description}}</p>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [ngClass]="{'row':index%5==0} Don't forget the quotes